# How to make the non-whitespace selector more selective

Tags: html, jquery, regex

I am trying to validate IDs for HTML 5, jQuery, and CSS

For HTML 5, it's pretty easy: basically just `\S+`. Yes, you do need one character, but in practice this is never an issue for me.

The problem is with jQuery. I need to weed out at least the apostrophe (') and quote (") characters, plus parenthesis '(' and ')'. When I try to use a jQuery selector like: #he(llo) it throws an Exception.

Right now I am validating my ids negatively in two steps. First, check for matches with '\s', then with the specific characters mentioned above.

I am just wondering if it is possible to do this in 1 regex - especially like "check for \S, plus..." ex. `[\S\'\"\(\)]`

Comment: Do you mean `[^\s'"()]+`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wont something like this work

```
[^\s'"()]+
```